# Wordpress Functions - How to use Replace String func. to add some code

Tags: php, wordpress

I had previously used a bit of code I found to add "rel = shadowbox" to my links in Wordpress (Which works like a charm).

```
/*
Plugin Name: Add shadowbox
*/
define("IMAGE_FILETYPE", "(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)", true);
function addlightboxrel_replace($string) {
    $pattern = '/<a(.*?)href="(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)"(.*?)>/i';
    $replacement = '<a$1href="$2.$3" rel=\'shadowbox\'$4>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'addlightboxrel_replace');
```

I had to use a separate plugin to add some gallery images. This plugin however didn't wrap the thumbnail image in an "a" tag (and there's no option to do such). So rather than edit the plugin, I am trying to use the same replace idea to add a link around the image.

I don't quite understand the first replace code, so I'm sure I'm missing something. I'm also trying to replace more than one line of code, so I'm not sure if that's where it's breaking. This is what I have:

```
define("IMAGE_FILETYPE", "(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)", true);
function addlink_replace($string) {
    $pattern = '/<ul class="slides"(.*?)><li(.*?)><img(.*?)src=(.*?)><(.*?)li><(.*?)ul>/i';
    $replacement = '<ul class="slides"$1><li$2><a src="$4"><img$3src=$4></a><$5li><$6ul>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'addlink_replace');
```

This is the current code being spit out by the plugin:

```
<ul class="slides" style="width: 600%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <li style="float: left; display: block; width: 100px;">
        <img width="110" height="110" class="slider-247 slide-243" alt="" src="http://carerforklifts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/F16H-1-110x110.jpg" draggable="false">
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I would like to wrap a "a" tag around the image, using the current images URL for the a tag's src. (If possible I need to remove that "-110x100" bit at the end of the jpg.

```
<ul class="slides" style="width: 600%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <li style="float: left; display: block; width: 100px;">
        <a src="http://carerforklifts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/F16H-1.jpg">
            <img width="110" height="110" class="slider-247 slide-243" alt="" src="http://carerforklifts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/F16H-1-110x110.jpg" draggable="false">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Currently working on this site if that helps: http://www.carerforklifts.com/f16-h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you have isn't going to match properly, it's missing several things. I've changed and simplified it a bit, so if the structure of the unordered list isn't the same every time you may need to modify this. Here is the regex updated in the function:

```
function addlink_replace($string) {
    $pattern = '/<ul(.*?)class="slides"(.*?)<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/ul>/is';
    $replacement = '<ul$1class="slides"$2<a href="$4"><img$3src="$4"$5></a>$6</ul>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
```

Basically this will match any unordered list that has the class `slides`, followed by anything up to an image tag, it will capture anything before the source attribute, it will capture the image source itself, anything in the image tag after the source attribute, then anything up to the closing tag of the unordered list.

The replacement will be the same string, but with the anchor tag around the image with the `href` attribute the same as the image `src`.

I made a sample output of this on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eR9pF6), there is a detailed explanation in the right side column of what it's matching.

Comment: Wow I appreciate the really in-depth answer and explanation there. It still doesn't seem to be adding the code however, but I'll take a look at that regex101 thing and see if I can't play around with it a bit.

Also the structure of the list is always the same <ul class="slides"><li><img></li></ul>, but some of the attributes in these tags might change...is that the issue?

Comment: This should catch changing and adding attributes (unless `class="slides"` changes). The regex should work if the HTML structure is the same as the example provided; it's possible that this filter is running too soon. You can set the priority later by changing the filter call to `add_filter('the_content', 'addlink_replace', 9999);`

Comment: What element on the linked page are you trying to apply this to? Is it the three small images of forklifts underneath the large image?

Comment: Yup those three images! class="slides" never changes, so your addition of ", 9999" totally worked. The images are now loading in the shadowbox (once I added the rel attribute as the other regex I had for that no longer worked). I just have to figure out how to get the non-thumbnail versions to load now. I will probably just store the URL in a variable, hack off the last 8 characters, and then use that to link with. THANKS so much, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: If there a way to save that "$4" in the "href" as a variable, and then spit out the new variable in the replacement code instead?

Comment: vvanasten - It only seems to add the link the first "li" in the ul list, and not all of them...

Comment: I think I've rewritten it to do what you're looking for. I have the code itself on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HcpbwpQ1) and a running example on [PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7938cbb7a8637b9007cabe94005ab990eff2c77). If you can, I would advise modifying the plugin to get the output you want rather than using this regex as it's complicated and may be hard to maintain in the future if the HTML changes. Hope this helps!

Comment: I noticed in the PHP Sandbox each img tag was loose in the li tag. In my actual code each img tag is wrapped in an li. So it's still only accessing the first IMG tag. I will read through what you sent, and try to understand it, and see if I can't get it working. Also I would normally change the output, but it's coming from a wordpress plugin, so if I ever needed to update it, I would lose all the changes.

Comment: I created a new function that I think does what you want on the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418377/removing-characters-from-a-variable-created-using-preg-replace/) you asked.

Comment: Odd, I tried that first thing this morning, and it didn't work. I restarted my comp and now it seems to be fine! So rather than using the "$4" directly you stored the matches in an array, and then modified it from there? I think I mostly understand how it's working. Thanks so much for the help!!