# Removing characters from a variable created using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, html-parsing, preg-replace

So I'm trying to hack off a few characters at the end of a URL I'm getting from a preg_replace function. However it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not familiar with using these variables in preg_replace (it was just something I found that "mostly" worked).

Here's my attempt:

```
function addlink_replace($string) {
    $pattern = '/<ul(.*?)class="slides"(.*?)<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/ul>/is';
    $URL = substr($4, 0, -8);;

    $replacement = '<ul$1class="slides"$2<a rel=\'shadowbox\' href="'.$URL.'"><img$3src="$4"$5></a>$6</ul>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'addlink_replace', 9999);
```

Basically I need to remove the last bit of my .jpg file name, so I can show the LARGE image rather than the THUMBNAIL it's generating, but the "$4" doesn't seem to want to be manipulated.

Comment: can you do a string replace on just the part you need to replace?

Comment: Ibu - That's what I'm trying to do with the $URL variable and substr. I'm trying to grab that "$4" which is my url in a string, deleted the last 8 characters, and then use the new variable $URL in my replace. However I'm not sure the variables created from the regex thing can be changed? I haven't tried to manipulate them before. If I do $URL = 'test'; then 'test' shows up in my code. But trying to use $4 I get an error saying UNEXPECTED '4'

Comment: It could help if you provided example data for us.

Comment: Please post an example of the source and the desired output so we can help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based off of what you're looking to accomplish in this question with the HTML structure of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414636/wordpress-functions-how-to-use-replace-string-func-to-add-some-code). The regex that is posted in your question will not match anything other than the first set of `<li>` and `<img>` tags , and [you've indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414636/wordpress-functions-how-to-use-replace-string-func-to-add-some-code#comment35887072_23415401) that you need to match all `<li>` and `<img>` tags within a `<ul>` so I've written a larger function to do so.

It will wrap all `<img>` tags that are inside of an `<li>` within a `<ul>` with the class of `slides` with an `<a>` with the source being the image's URL with the `-110x110` string removed, while preserving the thumbnail source in the `<img>` tag.

```
function addlink_replace($string) {
    $new_ul_block = '';
    $ul_pattern = '/<ul(.*?)class="slides"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/ul>/is';
    $img_pattern = '/<li(.*?)>(.*?)<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/li>/is';

    preg_match($ul_pattern, $string, $ul_matches);

    if (!empty($ul_matches[3]))
    {
        preg_match_all($img_pattern, $ul_matches[3], $img_matches);

        if (!empty($img_matches[0]))
        {
            $new_ul_block .= "<ul{$ul_matches[1]}class=\"slides\"{$ul_matches[2]}>";

            foreach ($img_matches[0] as $id => $img)
            {
                $new_img = str_replace('-110x110', '', $img_matches[4][$id]);
                $new_ul_block .= "<li{$img_matches[1][$id]}>{$img_matches[2][$id]}<a href=\"{$new_img}\">";
                $new_ul_block .= "<img{$img_matches[3][$id]}src=\"{$img_matches[4][$id]}\"{$img_matches[5][$id]}></a>{$img_matches[6][$id]}</li>";
            }

            $new_ul_block .= "</ul>";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($new_ul_block))
    {
        $replace_pattern = '/<ul.*?class="slides".*?>.*?<\/ul>/is';
        return preg_replace($replace_pattern, $new_ul_block, $string);
    }
    else
    {
        return $string;
    }
}
```

The change of the `<a>`'s `href` attribute from what the image had is specifically done on the line

`$new_img = str_replace('-110x110', '', $img_matches[2][$id]);`

if you would like to modify it. If you need to remove anything other than `-110x110` from the URL you may need to change it from `str_replace` to a `preg_replace`, or if you want to remove a specific number of characters from the end of the URL, you could use `substr`:

`$new_img = substr($img_matches[2][$id], 0, -12);`

Where `-12` is the number of characters you want to remove from the end of the string (it's negative because it's starting at the end).

I've posted a working example of this function [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a6d5a261c4c5cdbcc591e20359365c2c5afa2bd).

You may want to consider modifying the source of what is generating this code block, rather than using this regex, as this regex may be hard to maintain in the future if the HTML structure changes.

Comment: the -110x110 shouldn't change, as all the thumbnails are the same size, but I might just chop off the last 8 characters in case the client decides to change the thumb size. Also I would love to modify the original code, but as it's a wordpress plugin I tend to try and modify things in the functions so I don't run into trouble with updates. I just haven't had much experience with regex stuff before. Thanks so much for all your help wanasten, you're a real lifesaver!